# DataTable sorting and session scope not working

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces

**The sorting of simple data-table example is working with Controler's view scope but not with session**.
I have provided my code bellow for more info.
A list of users data populates a table.

Does anybody have a clue why such behavior?

**Model**

```
...
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long mId;
    private String mUsername;
    private String mPassword;
    private String mEmail;
    private Date mBirthdate;

    public User() { 
    }

    public User(Long aId, String aUsername, String aPassword, String aEmail,
            Date aBirthdate) {
        super();
        mId = aId;
        mUsername = aUsername;
        mPassword = aPassword;
        mEmail = aEmail;
        mBirthdate = aBirthdate;
    }

    ....
}
```

**Controller**

```
...    
@Controller("register")
@Scope("session")
public class Register implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private User mUser;
    private List<User> mUsers = new LinkedList<User>();
    private char[] mChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

    public Register() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        mUser = new User();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mUsers.add(new User(1L, randStr(3)+"_user", randStr(1)+"pass", randStr(1)+"user@mail.com", new Date()));
        }
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return mUser;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return mUsers;
    }

    public void submit() {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Registration successful");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
    private String randStr(int len){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char c = mChars[random.nextInt(mChars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<p:dataTable value="#{register.users}" var="usr" paginator="true" rows="4" sortBy="#{usr.username}">
    <p:column headerText="a" sortBy="#{usr.username}">
        <h:outputText value="#{usr.username}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="b" sortBy="#{usr.password}">
        <h:outputText value="#{usr.password}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="c" sortBy="#{usr.email}">
        <h:outputText value="#{usr.email}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: what is viewscope implementation are you using? What are you mean about "not working"? Could you provide some stracetrace?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `@Scope` from `org.springframework.context.annotation` package and not one from `javax.inject` package?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using `org.springframework.stereotype.Controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found what's the problem.

Although it's using AJAX the data-table has to be wrapped in `<h:form>`.

However in `view` scope that's not required, strange...

Thanks for your kind cooperation, appreciate it.